# angularjs bound value changes from inside directives are not reflected outside

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm testing out the behavior of bound variables from inside directives and I can't seem to get the view to be refreshed.  The model is being updated according to the console log, and I call $appy(), but for some reason the view refuses to be updated.  Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alanngai/D6D8J/4/)!

Here's the html

```
<div ng-app="foo">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div my-directive val="val" checked="checked" refresh="refresh"></div>
        <p>val (outside directive): {{val}}<p/>        
        <p>checked (outside directive): {{checked}}<p/>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the javascript

```
angular.module('foo', []).directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            val: "=",
            checked: "=",
            refresh: "="
        },
        template: '<p>val (inside directive): {{val}}</p>' +
                    '<p>checked (inside directive): {{checked}}</p>' +
                    '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked">checked',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var count = 0;
            //scope.val = "initialized";            
            scope.$watch('checked', function() {
                scope.val = "new value" + count;
                count += 1;
                console.log("updated val is: " + scope.val);
                scope.refresh();
            });
        } // link
    }; // return
}); // angular.module

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.val = "initial value";
    $scope.checked = false;   
    $scope.$watch('val', function(newVal) {
        console.log("newVal is: " + newVal);
    });
    $scope.refresh = function() {
        // none of the following lines make a difference
        if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();
        // $scope.$apply();
        // if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$digest();
        // $scope.$digest();        
        console.log("val is: " + $scope.val);
        console.log("checked is: " + $scope.checked);        
    }; // refresh    
} // MyCtrl
```

Comment: which version of angular js you are using

Comment: seems to be a fiddle issues see the working plunker copy http://plnkr.co/edit/3xbOwCDuhBK5vO8a7hEp?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you simply change the version of angularjs in your fiddle from 1.1.1 to 1.2.1.